# How to Listen for Socket on high numbered port

Tags: sockets, socket.io, windows-server-2008, asyncsocket

My chat server wasn't working on port 6667 (a common irc chat server port), so I switched it to port 844 and it works fine now.  I had my firewall disabled, but something was still preventing remote connections to port 6667....  This is on Windows Server 2008, a virtual server with GoDaddy.

Does anyone know how to unblock the higher port numbers?

Comment: if you're dead sure it's nothing in your code / firewall then I would check with GoDaddy and ask what the problem might be. Alternatively you could use tcpdump or other packet monitoring apps to see what is going on

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see at this link, GoDaddy blocks port 6667 to prevent abuse.

http://support.godaddy.com/groups/dedicated-linux/forum/topic/tcp-server-getting-started/

If that information is up-to-date, there's really nothing you can do without contacting GoDaddy support and ask to have it unblocked.

Edit: Better link and yes, it seems accurate that there are blocks.
http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/centos-vps-irc/